# Как убрать невидимый отступ и почему элементы внутри дива нужно центрировать отдельно

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(231, 116, 116), rgb(250, 250, 250) 65%);
}

.main-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-name {
    margin-top: 5vh;
}

.switcher-name {
    margin-top: 7vh;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(131, 122, 122);
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    font-size: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./popup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-target">
      <div class="main-div">
        <h1 class="main-name">Innuendo Solutions</h1>
        <p class="switcher-name">Софт сейчас выключен</p>
        <button class="button">On</button>
       </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Делаю хром расширение, так что размер нормальный подобран. Вопрос в том, почему display: flex, align-items: center, justify-content: center работает на тексте других элементов, а на последнем не работает. Ещё, если сделать display: flex, justify-content: center внутри последнего дива, то у текста сверху появится отступ, который нигде не отображается. Что это и как его убрать?

[image: div]

Answer (score 0):

> почему display: flex, align-items: center, justify-content: center работает на тексте других элементов, а на последнем не работает.

Потому что это работает не на "других элементах", а на `main-div`, и с ним всё нормально. Расстановка выполняется для его непосредственных потомков и исходя из их габаритов. У первых двух этих потомков габариты не заданы, поэтому они соответствуют по размерам своему содержимому. Грубо говоря, центрируется не текст, а содержащие его элементы. Но у последнего элемента у вас задана ширина - вот он и отцентрирован внутри парента по своей ширине. А вот текст внутри него не имеет стилей, заставляющих его центрироваться, потому и "не работает".

> если сделать display: flex, justify-content: center внутри последнего дива, то у текста сверху появится отступ, который нигде не отображается. Что это и как его убрать?

Какой браузер и ось? Проверил под виндой в хроме и ФФ - никаких лишних отступов нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Если делать в последнем диве align-items: center и justify-content: center, то текст будет немного смещен вниз, но если див поменять на button, то текст станет ровным. Если нужно, могу приложить скрин.

Comment: а приложите. и браузер напишите тоже.

Comment: Посмотрел, в хроме немного отличается, но в опере нет.

Comment: странно, у меня в хроме никаких отступов.
попробуйте вместо центрирования флексами обычный text-align